# SQL using CHECK IN on substring

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have added a check constraint on one of my attributes named "CONTACT" as follows :

```
CONSTRAINT CONTACTCORRECTNESS  CHECK ( SUBSTRING(CONTACT , 1 , 4) IN    
('0300', '0301', '0302', '0303', '0304', '0305', '0306', '0307', '0308', 
'0309' ,'0341', '0342', '0343', '0344', '0345', '0346', '0347', '0331', '0334', 
'0333', '0334', '0335', '0336', '0321', '0322', '0323', '0324', '0325', 
'0311', '0312', '0313', '0314', '0315'))
```

Assume that the contact number is always 11 digits long and is a varchar value , the goal here is to get the first four digits of every new contact entry as it gets fed into the database and verify that either they match one of the string in the set mentioned above(The set of strings from within the check constraint above).

I have used the above approach but it does not work as desired even on correct contact numbers a constraint violation occurs. HELP NEEDED !

Comment: Works here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5592f/1

Comment: I had the same results - no problem doing it. Are you inserting multiple rows at once? Maybe one of them is violating the constraint?

Comment: Yes I was inserting multiple rows at first. Then I inserted only one row which should not have violated the constraint but it did. Ultimately I had to remove the constraint

Comment: I think I inserted values with some sort of whitespaces maybe .Anyhow thanks guys for conforming that it works.

Answer (score 0):

use Rtrim and Ltrim inside substring and then try it....

```
CONSTRAINT CONTACTCORRECTNESS  CHECK ( SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONTACT)) , 1 , 4) IN    
('0300', '0301', '0302', '0303', '0304', '0305', '0306', '0307', '0308', 
'0309' ,'0341', '0342', '0343', '0344', '0345', '0346', '0347', '0331', '0334', 
'0333', '0334', '0335', '0336', '0321', '0322', '0323', '0324', '0325', 
'0311', '0312', '0313', '0314', '0315'))
```